# Extracting an HTML table with Perl

Tags: perl, cpan

I have the following table :

```
<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="label">Label1< /pan> 
            </td>
            <td>
                label1_value1
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="label">Label2</span> 
            </td>
            <td>
                            Label2_value1 <br/>
                            Label2_value2 <br/>

            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
            <td>
                <span class="label">Label3</span> 
            </td>
            <td>

                Result 1<br/>

                Result 2<br/>
                <span class="related"> - 
                                                     Result 1  SP2<br/> </span>
            </td>
        <\tr>
</table>
```

I want to use HTML::TableExtract in order to extract this table

I use the following code in order to extract the table :

```
$te->parse($table_content);
foreach my $row ($te->rows) {
    if (defined($row->[1])) {
        $row->[1]=~s/^\s+//gm;
        $row->[1]=~s/\s+$/;/gm;
        print $row->[1],"\n";
    }
}
```

I want the result on this format :

```
label1_value1,label1_value1;label1_value2,result1;result2-result3
```

but i get wrong results could someone help what the problem with my code or if its possilbe to parse spans with HTML::TableExtract

I get the following:
label1_value1
Label2_value1
Label2_value2;

result1

result2

-

reuslt1;

Comment: What results **are** you getting?

Comment: You should fix the fourth line of your table: `<span class="label">Label1< /pan>` should have a `</span>` at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, there are some errors in your HTML such as `</pan>` and `<\tr>` and an unclosed `span` tag. Once those are fixed, the code

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings; use strict;
use HTML::TableExtract;

my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new(
    attribs => {
        cellpadding => '4', cellspacing => '0', border => '0'
    }
);

my ($table) = $te->parse(do { local $/; <DATA>} );
for my $row ( $table->rows ) {
    for my $cell (@$row) {
        $cell =~ s/^\s+//;
        $cell =~ s/\s+\z/;/;
        $cell =~ s/\s+/ /g;
    }
    print join("|", @$row), "\n";
}
```

will give you:

```
Label1;|label1_value1;
Label2;|Label2_value1 Label2_value2;
Label3;|Result 1 Result 2 - Result 1 SP2;
```

Now, I do not know what logic would lead from that to your desired output of:

```
label1_value1,label1_value1;label1_value2,result1;result2-result3
```

Could you please provide more information on what you are trying to do?